# How valueBinding works in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Honestly i didn't find much helpful guides on emberjs.com about valueBindings.

*//login_route.js*

```
    App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return Ember.Object.create();
        }
    });
```

Basically here i'm creating empty JS object to be model for login template.
*//login.hbs*

```
  ...
  {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="email" id="email"}}
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="password" type="password" id="password"}}
  ...
```

So when user start to type user&pass, behind the scenes, Ember will crate 2 properties named "email" and "password" and 'append' them to context(model) of the current template and properties will be constantly updated till user hit login button ?

I can guess that is correct because i can do simple debug inside template:
`{{ email }}` (which is equal to `{{ controller.email }}` which again is equal to `{{ controller.model.email }}`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueBinding` essentially is telling Ember to bind the property named `password` to the internal property in Ember.TextField named `value`.

additionally you can just bind it to the property, like so

```
{{view Em.TextField value=email id="email"}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xujugayo/1/edit

Now the reason that

`{{ controller.email }}` is equal to `{{ controller.model.email }}` because the controller backing your template is an `ObjectController`.  The `ObjectController` is a proxy object, meaning it will proxy properties from the model that's backing it, as if they were on the controller.

Comment: Ok, i understand 2nd part.
I didn't understand part about Ember.TextField value property.
What magic allows to output model.email? How "email" ends as model property? 

And is this sentence correct: "So when user start to type user&pass, behind the scenes, Ember will crate 2 properties named "email" and "password" and 'append' them to context(model) of the current template and properties will be constantly updated till user hit login button ?"
Thanks on your time.

Comment: if a property doesn't exist, ember will create a property for you (as undefined).

Comment: on whatever the context is (in that particular case the model)